# nginx redirect all www domains to non-www domains

Tags: nginx, nginx-location

We are running nginx and hosting multiple domains on it.

We'd like to redirect all the www.domain to non-www domain. Is there a way to do it for all the servers at once without configuring individual servers. For example, I know I can achieve it for one server by following configuration, but I am looking for a solution which matches all the domains

```
server {
    server_name  www.example.com;
    return       301 https://example.com$request_uri;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
server {
     server_name "~^www\.(.*)$";
     return 301 https://$1$request_uri;
}
```

Use nginx regexp server_name to achieve it. https://nginx.ru/en/docs/http/server_names.html

Comment: This reads more as a follow-up Question than an Answer, and would be more appropriate as a Comment below the main Question.  If you are attempting to portray an Answer, then please include more of an explanation of how your Answer works and solves the Questioner's problem.

Answer (score 2):

Thank you all and Alexander. I finally used this by adding $scheme to your answer

```
server {
        server_name "~^www\.(.*)$" ;
        return 301 $scheme://$1$request_uri ;
}
```

Comment: that worked perfectly when i added it to nginx.conf :)